# Regular non-orthodox semigroups

Tags: semigroups, gap

Is there a resource somewhere with <strike>smallest</strike> finite and other examples of regular semigroups that are not orthodox? I want concrete examples for my private research. I once installed GAP and two semigroup packages too but I have no idea how difficult it would be to calculate such examples there, I haven't used GAP before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Just apply the definition. An [orthodox semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_semigroup) is a regular semigroup whose set of idempotents forms a subsemigroup. Thus you are looking for a regular semigroup in which there are two idempotents whose product is not idempotent. You should be able to find a 5-element regular semigroup with this property.

**Edit**. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2037952) for a complete description of the minimal counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one finite semigroup of order 4 whose idempotents don't form a subsemigroup (up to anti-isomorphism), and has the following Cayley table:

\begin{array}{l|llll}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4
\end{array}

Sadly it is not regular. It has 3 idempotents and one non-regular element (the 2).

However it might be possible to extend this semigroup by adding another element that should become an inverse of 2:

\begin{array}{l|lllll}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &   \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 &   \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
5 &   & 4 & 5 &   &  
\end{array}

As I was writing this, I did a quick program and indeed this is possible: there is only one way to extend it and the resulting **regular non-orthodox semigroup** is this one:

\begin{array}{l|lllll}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
5 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 5
\end{array}

Comment: I am glad for this example, thank you. I also noticed my inaccuracy in my question: I am not interested in the smallest but just small semigroups so that it is easier to deal with, but also whatever else no matter the size. I feel very inexperienced with examples, they've always been tough for me to find.

Comment: Now I have checked this example more thoroughly. I noticed that V_1={1}, V_2={5}, V_3={3}, V_4={4}, V_5={2}, also E={1,3,4}. So by this, V_e is included in E for any idempotent e which means the semigroup has to be orthodox! At the same time, V_3V_4=34=2 is not included in V_(43)=V_1=1, so it is like not orthodox. Because of this, I started doubting the associativity. And I found that this is actually not a semigroup: (25)4=34=2 and 2(54)=21=1. If you could fix this, it would be nice. Now I will go on with Jean-Eric's example.

Comment: I must have copied the wrong matrix. I edited the post and put the one that should work.Turns out that 5 is idempotent and is an inverse of 2 at the same time, with 3 and 4 as their left/right identities.

Comment: OK, now this is associative and it is actually the same example Jean-Eric gave: 1<->0, 2<->d=ab, 3<->a, 4<->b, 5<->c. This example has been very interesting to me. Thank you for efforts. There's only one question left: is this really the only one with 5 elements and there are no 4 element examples?

Comment: Yeah I noticed it ended up being the same too. It could be possible that it's the only example for semigroups with 5 elements, but I can't really tell. You might want a similar idempotent structure for regular non-orthodox semigroups so it's plausible. As for the 4 element case, I'm fairly sure there aren't such semigroups and the one I showed before is the only non-orthodox semigroup with 4 elements, but it isn't regular.